# Need Regular Expression to Only to have + sign and digits only min 10 max 15

Tags: regex, validation

I need a regex to validate phone numbers:

Conditions:

1. It may have `+` sign at the beginning (optional)
2. Then followed by only digits
3. Minimum 10 digits
4. Maximum 15 digits

Thanks

Comment: There are many formats of valid numbers, this differs from country to country. Which countries phone number you want to check? Also add your efforts in the question.

Comment: So, `\+?\d{,15}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
^\+?\d{10,15}$
```

Explanation:

1. `^` marks start of the string
2. `\+?`  - where \ escapes + sign and ? makes it optional
3. `\d` digit between 0-9
4. `{10,15}` means minimum 10 digit and 15 means maximum 15
5. `$` marks end of the string

> P.S: Solomon Island has 5 digit phone numbers. With country code it
>   can be  8 digits

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVTQjy/3)

Comment: This is what I exactly wanted. So my question is not so stupid. Thanks a lot mate